# Unable to assign properties of list element in ngFor in angular2

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have below code

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" *ngFor="#data of lengthArray"  data-slide-to="data.index" class="data.class"></li>
```

I'm getting data lengthArray from a http service which as length of 2, I'm getting 2 li elements but properties are not assigned to them

I even tried assigning like this [data-slide-to]="data.index" and putting # even , all possible ways

In browser inspect element I can see as

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="data.index" class="data.class"></li>
```

where I expect to be

```
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
```

as per data in my lengthArrat i.e data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
 [attr.data-slide-to]="data.index" [class]="data.class"
```

Without `[]` or `{{}}` Angular doesn't evaluate the value at all.

```
data-slide-to="data.index" class="data.class"
```

is therefore added as-is.

Angular2 by default binds to properties. There is no `data-slide-to` property on any element unless it is an Angular2 component and it has an `@Input('data-slide-to')`

To bind to attributes use either

```
[attr.attrname]="value"
```

or

```
attr.attrname="{{value}}"
```

to bind to an attribute instead of an property and to indicate that Angular2 needs to resolve the value.

Comment: Awesome bro for the quick reply trying all combinations from almost 1hr.